# How to replace elements of array

Tags: c++

I need help on how to replace the values of an array with a new string:

```
char cstring[MAX];
void remove(char * cstring)
{
std::string str (cstring);
str.erase (0,1);
std::cout << "New String: " << str << '\n';
}
```

How can I replace the values of `cstring` with the values of `str`?

Comment: If it is not intended that the parameter is the same as the global, please rename one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( str.size() >= MAX )
    throw......

std::strcpy(cstring, str.c_str());
```

note: The size check is not required if you are only erasing characters; however it makes your code more robust to include it, because you are less likely to introduce a bug in future by doing a different string operation and not realizing that you now actually do need to do the check.

NB. consider making `cstring` a `std::string` also! Then all these problems go away.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
void removeFirstCharacter()
{
    char* it = cstring;
    while (*it)
    {
        *it = *(it + 1);
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Or this?

```
void removeFirstCharacter(char* stringToChange)
{
    char* it = stringToChange;
    while (*it)
    {
        *it = *(it + 1);
        ++it;
    }
}
```